# How do I hide particular applications from launcher (taskbar / dock) on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I would like to hide icon, name and other existence of the particular applications from Launcher (taskbar if you wish).

Hence, I'm not able to install other popular desktop widgets like Conky Manager, I've installed an application called TZ Clock which allows us to set up multiple timezones, and customize the interface of the application.

The only problem is, it is also appearing in the launcher, which is not pleasing, so how do I hide applications from the launcher menu?.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on icon in launcher and choose "Remove from Favorites".